# How to calculate p value of prediction

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have the following regression:

```
> set.seed(20); y = rnorm(20); x = y + rnorm(20, 0, 0.2)
> lm = lm(y~x)
```

I ran:

```
> predict.lm(lm, data.frame(x=5), interval='prediction')
       fit      lwr      upr
1 4.586524 3.950506 5.222541
```

So obviously the prediction for y when x=5 is 4.5865.

Now I want to set a null to (y=5 when x=5) and calculate p-value (so that I can see whether I should reject the null).

p.s from the 95% interval I see that x=5 y=5 would not be rejected, but I want to calculate the exact p-value.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you "want to set a null to (y=5 when x=5)"?

Comment: `predict.lm` can return standard errors which would easily allow calculation of z-values.

Comment: The interpretation by standard errors, with difference $y-\hat{y}$, is a bit problematic (what does a null hypothesis y=5|x=5 mean?).

Alternatively you can re parameterize the model to be like y = a + b (x-5) such that the p-value of the parameter a is what you are looking for. 

In this case the interpretation is more in terms of the model rather than the prediction.

Comment: @Roland, can you please elaborate on the process that you suggested? And why it may be problematic?